# Does firebase support Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am going to develop a social media type application for iOS using Xamarin, for chat purpose I want to use firebase.

Can you please tell me if firebase is supported by Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: at this moment there is no good way to use Firebase features (analytics, crash reporting, pushes, etc) in Xamarin.iOS.  Best thread to get news about it is http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/201052/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like yes.

check this [nuget plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics/)

There is also a Xamarin.iOS project on [github](https://github.com/yamachu/TryFirebaseXamarin/blob/master/iOS/AppDelegate.cs) which uses FCM

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is a Xamarin compatible client available: https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp

Answer (score 1):

This one is for Firebase + Crashlytics for iOS only
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics/ it is published recently.

Other packages (Xamarin.Firebase.Crash for example) are for Firebase Crash reporting, which is being phased out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)